# Pandas concatenation of multiple dataframes returns null values

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a dataframe (`df`), that I break down into 4 new dfs (`media`, `client`, `code_type`, and `date`). `media` has one column of null values, while the other three are only 1-dim dfs, each consisting of nulls. After replacing the nulls in each dataframe, I try to `pd.concat`to get a single df and get the result below.

```
 code_type
0   P
1   P
2   P
3   P
4   P
5   P

code_name   media_type  acq.    revenue
0   RASH    NaN         50.0     34004.0
1   100     NaN         10.0     1035.0
2   NEWS    NaN         61.0     3475.0
3   DR      NaN         53.0     4307.0
4   SPORTS  NaN         45.0     6503.0
5   DOUBL   NaN         13.0     4205.0

    client_id
0   2.0
1   2.0
2   2.0
3   2.0
4   2.0
5   2.0

    date
0   2016-08-15
1   2016-08-15
2   2016-08-15
3   2016-08-15
4   2016-08-15
5   2016-08-15
```

I `pd.merge` `media` with another a separate df to replace the NaNs under `media.media_type`, which appends a new `media_type_y`

```
code_name   media_type_x    acq.    revenue  media_type_y
0   RASH       NaN          282     34004.0  Radio
1   100        NaN          119     1035.0   NaN
2   NEWS       NaN           81     3475.0   SiriusXM
3   DR         NaN           33     4307.0   SiriusXM
4   SPORTS     NaN           25     6503.0   SiriusXM
5   DOUBL      NaN           23     4205.0   Podcast
```

I then drop `media_type_x` and rename `media_type_y` to just `media_type`

```
final = m.loc[:,('code_name','media_type_y', 'acquisition', 'revenue')]
final = final.rename(columns={'media_type_y': 'media_type'})
```

So that when I concatenate, I have a complete df.

```
clean = pd.concat([media, client, code_type, date], axis=1)  

    code    media       acq.    revenue   client code_type  date
0   RASH    Radio       50.0    34004.0     NaN     NaN     NaT
1   100     NaN         10.0    1035.0      NaN     NaN     NaT
2   NEWS    SiriusXM    61.0    3475.0      NaN     NaN     NaT
3   DR      SiriusXM    53.0    4307.0      NaN     NaN     NaT
4   SPORTS  SiriusXM    45.0    6503.0      NaN     NaN     NaT
5   DOUBL   Podcast     13.0    4205.0      NaN     NaN     NaT
```

`clean.client` is supposed to be all `2`

`clean.code_type` should be all `P`

`clean.date` should be all `08/15/2016`

The dfs by themselves show the data, it's only when I concatenate that I lose the information. I think it may be something with the indexes, but I'm not sure. Could also be something to do with the fact that I have a column with both `str` and `int` (see `clean.code` above) which might be why I get the runtime error listed below.

> //anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/api.py:71: RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: int() < str(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
>     result = result.union(other)

Comment: Show sample content of these dfs individually?

Comment: Sorry! Edited to include dfs individually

Comment: Works pretty much for me. I don't see NaN https://paste.fedoraproject.org/414624/22374471/raw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
  code_name media_type  acq.  revenue
0      RASH      Radio  50.0  34004.0
1       100        NaN  10.0   1035.0
2      NEWS   SiriusXM  61.0   3475.0
3        DR   SiriusXM  53.0   4307.0
4    SPORTS   SiriusXM  45.0   6503.0
5     DOUBL    Podcast  13.0   4205.0
```

Try this:

```
df['client_id'] = 2
df['date']      = '08/15/2016'
df['code_type'] = 'P'
df

    code_name media_type  acq.  revenue  client_id        date code_type
0      RASH      Radio  50.0  34004.0          2  08/15/2016         P
1       100        NaN  10.0   1035.0          2  08/15/2016         P
2      NEWS   SiriusXM  61.0   3475.0          2  08/15/2016         P
3        DR   SiriusXM  53.0   4307.0          2  08/15/2016         P
4    SPORTS   SiriusXM  45.0   6503.0          2  08/15/2016         P
5     DOUBL    Podcast  13.0   4205.0          2  08/15/2016         P
```